# Fundamental group of the plane minus $n$ points

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, fundamental-groups

If I have a plane $\mathbb{R}^2,$ and I take out $n$ points, I can picture it wlog as the union of two planes, one without a point and one without $n-1$ points, and these two halves of the plane intersect at a line.

Since everything is open and path connected I can use Van Kampen to obtain that the $\pi_1$ of the plane minus $n$ points is the free product of the $\pi_1$ of the plane minus one point and the $\pi_1$ of the plane minus $n-1$ points.

Iterating this we get that the fundamental group of the plane minus $n$ points is the free product of the $\pi_1$ of the plane minus a point $n$ times.

But the plane minus a point can be retracted to a circle, hence what we have is the free product of $\mathbb{Z}$ with itself $n$ times.

I am posting this to check if my reasoning is correct.

Comment: It looks good to me.

Comment: We can prove it by induction on $n$ as well, noting that the fundamental group of the line of intersection is trivial.